# matplotlib auto yaxis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to interactively view a large dataset.  I'd like to zoom/pan the view without redrawing it for performance reasons.  It's easy to create the new x view range and apply it with `set_xlim(left,right)`.  But there does not seem to be an automatic way to show the new view with the y axis appropriately value limited based on the new x range.

`autoscale(enable=True, axis='y')` finds the y max and min from *all* the data drawn, and not restricted to the y data based on the x view limit.  Is there any such mode or function, or must `set_ylim()` be used with a manually calculated range?

Here is an example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.ioff()
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = plt.subplot(111, axisbg='black')

tick = np.arange(10)

ax.grid(b=True, color='white')
ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=False)
ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', tight=True)
ax.plot(tick, color='#ff3333', linestyle='-')

fig.canvas.draw()
raw_input('enter:')

ax.set_xlim(2, 5)
fig.canvas.draw()
raw_input('enter:')    

ax.set_xlim(1, 6)
fig.canvas.draw()
raw_input('enter:')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find a way through matplotlib to determine the rendered y limits based on x.

However, two factors seem to obviate the need for this.

1. matplotlib 1.2.1 has big performance gains over the previous version I was using.
2. For OS X, changing the backend from 'MacOSX' to 'TkAgg' saw big performance improvements for the line styles being used.

In sum, the gains were on the order of 10-20x, which made the interactive browsing of the dataset real-time, so no additional hacks were needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I submitted an answer to the wrong question!

But I should think that it is not that hard to manually calculate the range. Or you can use plt.ion() and zoom in appropriately with the magnifying glass.